# CSS animation in reverse

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following CSS:

```
@keyframes divFadeIn {
    0%{opacity:0; transform: scale(0.5)}
    100%{opacity:1; transform: scale(1)}
}

.overlay {
    position: relative;
    top: -$headerHeight;
    z-index: 1000;
    height: 100%;
    animation: divFadeIn 0.3s 1 ease-out;
}
```

This affects the DIV when I click a button it animates from the center to 100% width.

However, how do I get it so that it animates backwards when I click another  button??

So I click first button - animates to 100%

I click another button - animates the opposite way to 0%

Comment: Make another keyframes `divFadeOut` with opposite values, then onClick replace the animation name with `divFadeOut`

Comment: Have a look at this answer and it may help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35525992/reverse-a-css-animation/35533366#35533366. The solution is basically what Huy Nguyen has already said but the linked thread has some detailed explanation which should be useful for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your problem, you can create another keyframes `divFadeOut` with opposite values with `divFadeIn` (animates the opposite way to 0%) and create a class `fadeOut` with content:

```css
.fadeOut {
    animation: divFadeOut 0.3s 1 ease-out;
}
```

Remove `animation` from class `overlay` and add to class `fadeIn`:

```
.fadeIn {
    animation: divFadeIn 0.3s 1 ease-out;
}
```

When you click button, you can remove or add one of above animations to DIV with following code. In case, i use jQuery implement:

```
$('#button1').click(function() {
    $('.overlay').addClass('fadeIn');
});

$('#button2').click(function() {
    $('.overlay').removeClass('fadeIn');
    $('.overlay').addClass('fadeOut');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this fully with CSS as far as I know. You'll have to use some JS to trigger an onClick event and replace the class `divFadeIn` with something like `divFadeOut` which would reverse the opacity animation back to 0. This is especially true if you're trying to trigger this action with two different buttons.

**EDIT**
Adding on to the previous answer, here's a fiddle with a different approach but I believe the same effect

https://jsfiddle.net/yanv6gtz/4/