# How to change webkit animation to another animation in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a modal box like this:

```
<div id="main">
      <div id="myModal" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <video src="images/movie.mp4.mp4" autoplay muted class="videoPreview" id="video1"></video>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
          </div>
```

And in the css I have this animations:

```
.modal-content {
        position: relative;
        background-color: #fefefe;
        margin: auto;
        padding: 0;
        border: none solid #888;
        width: 80%;
        box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
        -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
        animation-name: animatetop;
        animation-duration: 1s
    }

    /* Add Animation */
    @-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
        from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
        to {top:0; opacity:1}
    }
    @keyframes animatetop {
        from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
        to {top:0; opacity:1}
    }
```

The animation makes the modal appear from top to the center of the screen when the user clicks on an element, and when the user clicks outside the modalBox It changes it's display to "none" but I actually want it to make the same animation but in reverse, that is, going from center screen to the top. So I've done this in css:

```
 @-webkit-keyframes animateexit
        {
          from{top: 0px; opacity: 0}
          to {top: -300px; opacity: 1}
        }
        @keyframes animateexit
        {
          from{top: 0px; opacity: 0}
          to {top: -300px; opacity: 1}
        }
```

And in the script I've tried to change

```
-webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
-webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
 animation-name: animatetop;
```

To this:

```
-webkit-animation-name: animateexit;
-webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
animation-name: animateexit;
```

and in javascript:

```
span.onclick = function() {
 //modal.style.display = "none";
 modal.style.WebkitAnimationName = "animateexit";
 modal.style.animation-name= "animateexit";
}
```

But once I do that the modal box doesn't appear at all.
What do I need to do to animate the modal box so it goes from the center to top instead of just closing when the user clicks the on the span outside the modal?

Here is a link to fiddle, I think it's easier to see that way https://jsfiddle.net/9kecL0no/

Comment: Where is span button ?

Comment: I've took out the close button, it closes when the user clicks outside the modal and opens when the user clicks on an element with the class "video"

Comment: I think you are facing the same issue that is mentioned in this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35525992/reverse-a-css-animation/35533366#35533366. That is when you change the animation from `animatetop` to `animateexit`, you are removing the `animatetop` animation which would make the element snap to its original position (and not remain in its current position). Thus the reverse animation (which is `animateexit`) probably has no visual effect.

Comment: I am not sure about marking this as a dupe because you say that you are modifying the `display` property also and generally changing the `display` property will cause all animations and transitions to break because that property is not at all animatable.

Comment: @Harry Im really new to JavaScript Im trying to aplly things I see and change them to what I need more or less like trial and error. I dont have a clue on how to animate the modal the way I want, well i guess I just apply the reverse animation as I tried but thats my only guess, if you think its a dupe make sure to mark it. We need to make SO cleaner and easier to find accurate info